# Accord avec « tu » et « vous »

Tags: accord, temps-composés

> Je t'ai / vous ai dite...

L'accord, s'adressant à une femme (tutoyer/vouvoyer respectivement), est-il obligatoire ou non ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ *dise* n'est pas le participe passé du verbe *dire*.

C'est ***dit*** le participe passé. Accordé au féminin on obtient ***dite***.
Au pluriel ***dits*** ou ***dites***.

2/ On peut, dans certains cas de conjugaison avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*, accorder le participe passé.
Mais, dans ces cas on l'accorde avec le complément d'objet **direct**.

Dans l'exemple que tu donnes, *t'* ou *vous* sont compléments d'objet **indirect** => pas d'accord.

*Je t'ai dit, je vous ai dit*

Qu'il s'agisse d'une femme d'un homme, qu'il y en ait plusieurs ou un(e) seul(e).

Comment: Merci de nouveau. Je viens de corriger. Grande faute ☺!

Comment: Pas de souçi dimitris. Si 1/ était effectivement fautif, je ne tiens pas l'accord du participe passé comme tel. De grands auteurs (Maupassant, Sand...) commettent des entorses à faire blêmir un grammairien mais... on les accepte sans problème car... ce sont de grands auteurs.

Comment: Au fait, il y a un petit livre portant le titre Les plus jolies fautes de français de nos grands écrivains concernant ton dernier commentaire.

Comment: Eh bien... Tu vois... Pour moi, si des fautes sont **jolies** alors... ce ne sont pas des fautes... ;) En littérature, poésie... la joliesse pardonne tout! Justifie tout! (J'aurais volontiers ajouté... c'est comme pour les femmes... si je ne craignais, par les temps qui courent... d'être suspecté de sexisme.) Or... il ne s'agit pas de sexisme... pas plus qu'il ne s'agit de grammaire... puisqu'il est bien ici question d'esthétique.

Comment: En revanche... mon *souci* avec un c cédile en post #2... lui... il est vraiment : PABO!